# Make POST https request in AWS Lambda without waiting for response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, https, request

I am trying to make an https request (API gateway call to other Lambda) in my AWS Lambda function with Node.js, but without waiting for the response, so when the data has already been sent to the other Lambda (and starts running), my first Lambda stops running.

What I've been trying to do is the following code:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
        hostname: 'example.com',
        path: '/example/action',
        method: 'POST'
    }
    const req = https.request(options);
    console.log('Request: ', req);
    req.on('error', error => {
        reject(error);
    });
    
    // Send data
    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    req.end(() => {
        // This is where (in theory) request has been made, and no response received
        resolve(req);
    });
});
```

It results in a timeout issue, due to resolve is never called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the Lambda or call the API gateway endpoint? If the first, you can just asynchronously invoke the Lambda without going via the API gateway endpoint. If second, your Lambda needs to return immediately and process the request in the background; the client (calling Lambda) can't do that.

Comment: For asynchronous invocation, take a look at the [AWS JS SDK v3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/invokecommand.html ) & set `InvocationType` to `Event`

Comment: I am calling the API gateway that is proxy integrated with the Lambda function. What you mean is calling the Lambda with aws-sdk right? Is it a better approach?

Comment: If you are looking to invoke the Lambda, yes it is - faster, cheaper & does exactly what you want while allowing you to also use IAM permissions.